# How to define the exact place of wrong variable in html component from the TypeScript stacktrace?

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

For my Angular app I have a stacktrace like:

`ERROR in src/main/webapp/app/businesslogic/kindergartenclass/create.kindergartenclass.component.html(1,2314): : Property 'subject' does not exist on type 'NgForm'.`

How can I identify the original problem point in the html markup of several lines. I tried to concatinate all rows to single and try to point 2314 there, put it definetely not pointing to any variable there.

Guys, especially those who vote for 'close', I have already found the problem itself, spending a lot of time parsing the template with my eyes... the question is how to find the wrong place in principle when the stacktrace point to some odd place in the template, not convertible to the real html template characters position. The represented stacktrace was just put as the example here.

The problem variable was fount at the template at 22:66 position and I still have NO IDEA how to use 1:SEVERALTHOUSANDSANDSOMELITTLETAIL format to identify the problem places if I still have the stacktrace and nothing else.

Hey, Angular guys, how do you find yourself patient enough to make debug ever possible under such conditions?

Comment: can you share the template code for `indergartenclass.component.html` ?

Comment: the error says Property 'subject' does not exist on type 'NgForm', find where u trying to access that property and try to fix it :)

Comment: guys, I have already found the problem itself, spending a lot of tyme parsing the template with my eyes... the question is how to find the wrong place in principle when the stacktrace point to some odd place in the template, not convertable to the real html template characters position

Comment: @Gaël Marziou have you faced the above problem?